# prove integrability of $f(|x|)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I would like some help on the following question.

$Let \ f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function.
prove that $f(|x|)$ is integrable in the closed - $k$ dimensional unit ball $B^k(0,1)$.

I tried using the Darboux sums but I could'nt find such partition that would make the Darboux sums of $f(|x|)$ converge.

Comment: what kind of integrable? Riemann? Lebesgue?

Comment: Then why deal with Darboux sums? Show (if you haven't already done so) that $f\circ |\cdot |$ is Lebesgue measurable and to show finiteness of the integral, one way is to use polar coordinates.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I'm not sure it's true for the case of $k \geq 2$

Comment: @Exodd Riemann integrable

Answer (score 1):

Now as you say you were trying to do by Darboux sums , I guess you were trying to prove it was Riemann integrable which is easy enough to do

Let $F_{n}:\Bbb{R}^{n}\to\Bbb{R}^{n}$ be the diffeomorphism

\begin{align}
x_1 &= r \cos(\varphi_1) \\
x_2 &= r \sin(\varphi_1) \cos(\varphi_2) \\
x_3 &= r \sin(\varphi_1) \sin(\varphi_2) \cos(\varphi_3) \\
    &\,\,\,\vdots\\
x_{n-1} &= r \sin(\varphi_1) \cdots \sin(\varphi_{n-2}) \cos(\varphi_{n-1}) \\
x_n     &= r \sin(\varphi_1) \cdots \sin(\varphi_{n-2}) \sin(\varphi_{n-1}) .
\end{align}

Then the Jacobian for the change of variables is given by $J_{n}=(r\sin(\varphi_1) \dotsm \sin(\varphi_{n-2}))|J_{n-1}|$ where $J_{n-1}$ is the jacobian for the diffeomorphism $F_{n-1}$.

Hence a simple induction shows that $|J_{n}|\leq 1 $ for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$ when $0\leq r\leq 1$.

The integral simply becomes :-

$$\int_{B[0,1]}f(|x|)\,dx = \int_{\varphi_{1},...,\varphi_{n-1}}\int_{0}^{1}f(r)|J_{n}|\,dr\,d\varphi_{1}...d\varphi_{n-1}\leq K\int_{0}^{1}f(r)\,dr<\infty$$ where $K$ is a finite positive constant determined by the ranges of $\varphi_{1},...,\varphi_{n-1}$ which are finite as the tuple $(\varphi_{1},...,\varphi_{n-1})$ must be coordinates for the sphere $S^{n-1}$.

However proving Lebesgue Integrability is a little more subtle affair

The following is from [Stein and Shakarchi Real Analysis](http://www.cmat.edu.uy/%7Emordecki/courses/medida2013/book.pdf) page 279.

Then the integral is:-

$$\int_{B[0,1]}f(|x|)\,d\lambda_{n}=\int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{\Bbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{r\in[0,1]}f(r)\cdot r^{n-1}\,d\lambda\, d\mu$$ where $\mu$ is the measure on the sphere $S^{n-1}$ treated as a measure space whose definition I give below and $\lambda_{n}$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}^{n}$.

Define a measure space $(X=S^{n-1},\mathcal{F},\mu)$ where $E\in\mathcal{F}$ if and only if the set $\hat{E}=\{x\in\Bbb{R}^{n} : \frac{x}{|x|}\in E\,,0<|x|<1\}$ is a Borel Measurable subset of $\Bbb{R}^{n}$ and $\mu(E)=n\cdot\lambda_{n}(\hat{E})$

Then by using the integrability of $f$ and the fact that $r\leq 1$ we have that by Fubini's Theorem :-

$$\int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{\Bbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{r\in[0,1]}f(r)\cdot r^{n-1}\,d\lambda\, d\mu\leq n\lambda_{n}(B[0,1])\int_{[0,1]}f(r)\,d\lambda<\infty$$.

Comment: Yes I was talking about Riemann integrability. I don't think you can use change of variables in order to prove integrability because one of the conditions for using this theorem is that the function which you make the composition with the diffeomorphism needs to be integrable.

Comment: No it does not require integrability. We only need measurability of $f\circ | \cdot |$ .  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables.  A proof of this can be found in any good measure theory book . See Stein and Shakarchi or H.Royden. Or even a good probability book like Rick Durrett will do